# grails change Date format in gsp view

Tags: date, grails, groovy, simpledateformat

When I try to use date format tag in gsp view to change the format of my date but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
class MyDate {  
    Date date
}
```

MyDateController:

```
....
def unixSeconds = params["date"].replaceAll("\"", "") as long  //params["date"]="1386157660"
Date date = new Date(unixSeconds*1000L)
myDateInstance = new MyDate(date:date)
....
```

gsp View:

```
${myDateInstance.date.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')}
```

The format that I have is 2013-12-04 12:47:40.0 instead of 2013-12-04 12:47

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Afaict, that shouldn't happen and I can't see how it is happening...

Are you sure that's the line of code that's generating the output you're seeing?

You could try the Grails formatDate tag in its place:

```
<g:formatDate format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" date="${myDateInstance.date}"/>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right: I need to change the date format in two places in my code...so my code is correct.

Comment: Additionally, I observed that if `type` and `style` are given, `format` is not used. I think they work as alternatives for each other. Also, using `format` would be beneficial as the Date string format could differ on different operating systems.

Comment: I tried with `format="MM/dd/yyyy"` but it fails to parse the date and gives the error `Unparseable date: "07/12/2019"`. Is there anywhere, where I can find how the `/` character is supposed to be used for the format?

Answer (score 8):

You can use "formatDate" in value attribute like following

```
<g:textField name="saleDate" value="${formatDate(format:'dd-MM-yyyy',date:saleItem?.saleDate)}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @tim_yates's answer above, there is another point I want to add:

I observed that if `type` and `style` are given, `format` is not used. I think they work as alternatives for each other. Also, using `format` would be beneficial as the Date string format could differ on different operating systems.