# Grails: error executing tag <g:formatDate>: unknown class: java.lang.String with root cause

Tags: date, grails, groovy

I have dates stored in my database in a format like this: 2017-04-12T00:00:00

I am displaying these on an index show page like so:

```
<td>${event.eventTime}</td>
```

I want to convert the date into a a regular format, I came across the grails formatDate tag.

I've tried variations of this but the error from the title still remains, where am I going wrong?

```
<td><g:formatDate date="${event.eventTime }" format="yyyy-MM-dd" /></td>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376729/grails-change-date-format-in-gsp-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that eventTime on your event object is a string rather than a date.

If you try the following as a test it should work:

```
<td><g:formatDate date="${new Date()}" format="yyyy-MM-dd" /></td>
```

Is eventTime stored as a date in the DB or maybe it's being converted en-route to the gsp?

To just strip off the time & keep the same format you could:

```
${event.eventTime?.substring(0, 10)}
```

Or you could convert to a date and back to another format:

```
<g:formatDate date="${Date.parse( "YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", event.getTime )}" format="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
```

Comment: You're dead right it is being stored as a String. I would rather not change the variable type now as my db has many valuable entries in it at this point. Do you know of any way around that?

Comment: If you just want to strip off the time you could just do `${event.eventTime?.substring(0, 10)}`

Comment: You could convert it to a date then into another format too e.g. `<g:formatDate date="${Date.parse( "YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", event.getTime )}" format="yyyy-MM-dd"/>`